How to component test Web API
I am trying to figure out how to component test my Web API. This used to be a simple process using TestServer and having a testable Startup class.
I tried:
        var foo = new WebApplicationFactory<Startup>();
        var bar = foo.CreateClient();
        var client = await bar.GetAsync($"/price/ada/adad/asas/v1/prices?itemNumber=123");


The problem is it hangs on creating the client with no feedback to what is happening.
I went down the route of using TestServer however, it seems I need to place my TestStartup class in the same assembly as Startup. I don't remember having to do this. Is it possible to have the TestStartup class live in my Test library and act the same way?
For example, this is my setup
public class Startup
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ILogger<Startup> logger)
    {
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => 
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        ConfigureExternalDependencies(services);

        services.AddControllers();
        services.AddRouting();
    }

    protected virtual void ConfigureExternalDependencies(IServiceCollection services)
    {
       // .. override external I/O stuff
    }
}


TestStartup looks like this:
public class TestStartup : Startup
{
    public TestStartup() : base(BuildConfiguration())
    {
    }
    
    protected override void ConfigureExternalDependencies(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddTransient<IGetMultiplePricesQuery>(_ => Substitute.For<IGetMultiplePricesQuery>());    
    }
    
    private static IConfiguration BuildConfiguration()
    {
        return new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddInMemoryCollection()
            .Build();
    }
}

When I use TestServer usage is as follows:
        var webHostBuilder = new WebHostBuilder().UseStartup<TestStartup>();
        _server = new TestServer(webHostBuilder);
        var client = _server.CreateClient();
        _httpResponse = await client.GetAsync($"/price/ada/adad/asas/v1/prices?itemNumber=123");

This works but I would like my TestStartup to not live in the production code space.

And how do you setup the app/server itself? Can you please add a fully runnable [mre]?
